# How to be an asp.net sign in provider

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net 5 mvc/webapi application that uses asp.net identity to sign on and it works fine. Lets call it "MyApp". Now I have the need to allow a third party system (on which I have no control) to sign on using "MyApp". On their site they will have a "log in using MyApp" button, like it is possible with facebook and google. I found a lot of content on how to consume a third party sign in provider but not on how to *be* one. The objective is to allow the users of MyApp to sign in on the third party app without explicitly having to create credentials on there. Can somebody give me some directions on what should I be looking for to make a MVP of this?

Comment: IdentityServer (4 or 3) should make it easier (although not easy) for you to provide sign on services. Although I found their documentation lacking. I'm not sure if using it to set up a server means that clients can use the built-in OAuth stuff in MVC or not, but I think clients also have to install the ID server libraries too. Aside from that you would be stuck writing your own logic to mint tokens and work out a protocol with the client apps for how to transfer and decrypt the token with some key.

Comment: It's probably going to take some work, and you'll learn about security, but http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/ is a good starting point.